# How to pass variable to JSON, for python?

Tags: python, json

I am new in work with JSON, so sorry in advance for the stupid question.

I want to write JSON with the variable in the value field. It looks like this:

```
def print_json(user_name):
    opened_json = open('way/to/json/file')
    tmp = json.load(opened_json)

    res = tmp(['path_to_folder'](user_name))
    print(res)

def main(user_name):
    print_json(user_name)


main('user')
```

It is JSON:

```
{"path_to_folder": "/Users/" + user_name + "/my_folder/"}
```

Awaiting for that output:

```
/Users/user/my_folder/
```

Please, tell me if any solution here exists.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT: My problem, that I can't add variable to JSON correctly. It marked red. Wrong syntax, when I try to concat.**

Comment: `res = tmp['path_to_folder']`

Comment: tmp will be a regular python dictionary containing the json object(dictionary) from your file.

Comment: JSON file does not let my to write it clear. There is no option to add variable.

Comment: I have no idea what your above comment means, sorry

Comment: "/Users/" + user_name + "/my_folder/"}
Impossible to add 'user_name'. Wrong syntax.

Comment: Edited the description.

Comment: `{"path_to_folder": "/Users/" + user_name + "/my_folder/"}` isn't valid JSON to start with.

Comment: Sorry, it's really unclear what you are asking. You have an existing json file, or you want to create a totally new json file?

Comment: Yes, I already know it. And can't make it valid, don't find correct syntax. That is a problem.

Comment: Only correct the JSON.

The idea: I pass 'user_name' to JSON, it put it to my value (in String) and I receive correct answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want isn't directly possible in JSON, because it doesn't support "templating".

One solution would be to use a templating language such as [Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/) to write a JSON template, then load this file without the `json` library and fill in the values using Jinja, and finally use `json.loads` to load a dictionary from your rendered string.

Your json-like file could look something like this:

```
{"path_to_folder": "/Users/{{ user_name }}/my_folder/"}
```

Your Python code:

```
import json
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader

env = Environment(
    FileSystemLoader("path/to/template")
)
template = env.get_template("template_filename.json")

def print_json(username):
    return json.loads(
        template.render(user_name=username)
    )
...
```

---

In fact, if this is a simple one-time thing, it might even be better to use Python's built-in templating. I would recommend old-style formatting in the case of JSON, because otherwise you'll have to escape a lot of braces:

JSON file:

```
{"path_to_folder": "/Users/%(user_name)s/my_folder/"}
```

"Rendering":

```
with open("path/to/json") as f:
    rendered = json.loads(f.read() % {"user_name": username})
```

Comment: Thank you! I though that it works like usual concat for string...

Comment: TypeError: no loader for this environment specified. Not sure, but maybe I made a mistake in code.

Comment: You'll have to give the `Environment` object some arguments, see [this](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/api/#basics). I'll change it in the answer.

Comment: The final editing works fine. Thank you!

Last question: my JSON consists of many rows and now it prints me all of them. How can I call specific value? Where I should add path to it?